# Conditional Operator and incements - could be so easy, or?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

Is there is a way to write an "do an increment or not" if clause a bit more lean.

I have the following code in my solution:

```
if (noRead)
{
   NoReadsInSequence++;
}
else
{
   NoReadsInSequence = 0;
}
```

My idea was to write it somehow like that...

```
NoReadsInSequence = noRead ? ++: 0;
```

But of course that does not work. How could i write that without having to write the variable NoReadsInSequence twice per line?

Comment: `NoReadsInSequence = noRead ? NoReadsInSequence++: 0;`

you were close , you didn't gave an operand to opeator.

Comment: Yeah i know ... BUT ... as the conditional operator has the ability to implicitely assign a value to an variable, i thught it should be possible to write something like that with an increment as well. Or ... should i just write +=1?

Comment: It still won't work with that, you need to tell what you  are appending to.

Comment: I would leave it as it is. Easy to read and understand.

Comment: @schwifty If `noRead` is true then executing `NoReadsInSequence = noRead ? NoReadsInSequence++: 0;` will leave `noRead` UNCHANGED.

Comment: It would have to be `NoReadsInSequence = noRead ? NoReadsInSequence + 1 : 0;`

Comment: Here is another suggestion, however less readable: `NoReadsInSequence+= noRead ? 1 : -NoReadsInSequence;`

Answer (score 4):

How about an extension method?

```
public static void DoAnIncrementOrNot(this ref int value, bool flag)
{
    value = flag ? value + 1 : 0;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
int value = 5;
value.DoAnIncrementOrNot(true);
value.DoAnIncrementOrNot(true);
value.DoAnIncrementOrNot(true);
Console.WriteLine(value);
value.DoAnIncrementOrNot(false);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

That outputs `8` then `0`.

Comment: Thats an solution - need to think if this cleans up the code or adds a bit more complexity to it (in terms of understanding what is going on).

Comment: @MartinHertig - Correct. It does both of those things.

Comment: Note that suggested extension method *should not* work for @MartinHertig because they have *property*  `NoReadsInSequence` and you can't use `ref` with those...